# MacOS unable to find Qt5 path

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, qt5

I have the GUI version qt5 installed with 5.15.1 also installed with it, it is unable to find the path as follows. My qt5 path is `/Users/someuser/Qt/5.15.1/`

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Default paths
# - CMake's path finder is completely useless for Qt5 + Python on Win64
# - allow override from command line on OsX, eg use "cmake ..  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/someone/qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/

if(APPLE)
    if(NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
        set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/opt/qt5/") #  mac/homebrew (version independent)
        #set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/someuser/Qt/5.15.1/clang_64") #  other...
    endif()
endif()
```

My error:

```
No Qt5 found (recommended!), trying to use Qt4
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1314 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:644 (find_package)
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding it in the cmakelists.txt, you would usually pass the Qt path via -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/Qt/5.15.1/clang_64 to cmake, or add $HOME/Qt/5.15.1/clang_64/bin to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error in the script logic:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
```

this block of code will be executed if `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is [evaluated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) to the false constant only. If there will be other values in this list, it will not be changed.

Instead, you should use:

```cmake
if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/opt/qt5/")
    # or list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/someuser/Qt/5.15.1/clang_64")
endif()
```

Comment: [link] (https://pastebin.com/1p9mhzxg) this is my CMakeOutput.log, i tried with the changes you suggested but it still does not work, any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: There are any errors in the log file you submitted to PasteBin. Also, there are no any "qt5"-related messages in that file.